# Can't use CSS Variables inside of filter grayscale with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

I'm trying to make the `100%` in `filter: grayscale(100%);` be a CSS variable so I can dynamically change it later with JavaScript.

```css
--percent: 100%;
filter: grayscale(var(--percent));
```

This is not compiling with Dart sass. It's telling me:

> Dart Sass failed with this error: $color: var(--percent) is not a color. filter: grayscale(var(--percent));

Which doesn't make any sense to me as it works [just fine with normal CSS](https://codepen.io/bdlowery/pen/oNqMWQw).

How can I get this normal CSS Variable to work with Dart Sass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it conflicts with [the grayscale function of Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#grayscale) and Sass-specific functions can't handle CSS variables.

Use it this way:

```
--percent: 100%;
filter: #{"grayscale(var(--percent))"};
```